# Determining Smartphone / Non-Smartphone for php

Tags: php, mobile, smartphone, wap, device-detection

It seems like facebook has this mastered, I've checked a bit into WURFL but this seems like an extremely expensive process.  I've also checked out: [url](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-php) link. While it has a good list of user agents, I'm trying to identify which are smart phones and which are not.

facebook pushes the non-smart phones to a different site than their smart phones. Trying to see if there was an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [Tera-WURFL](http://www.tera-wurfl.com/) which is basically WURFL serialized data in a MySQL database. Much better performance than XML WURFL.

There is also another mobile device db out there: [Device Atlas](http://deviceatlas.com/).

What you could do is find the lowest common denominator for smartphones, then create your own stripped down version of WURFL / Device Atlas which would be far less resource intensive and faster to check, and go from there.

Comment: Cheers! Worked perfect. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Screen size should be a somewhat reliable indicator. Non-smarts tend to have less than 320x240 resolution, though I'd check some older smartphone models to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try **wurfl-php-1.4.2.0**

```
$isPhone = $device->getCapability("can_assign_phone_number");
$isSmarty = $device->getCapability("device_claims_web_support");
```

If it is a phone and smart, it is a smartphone. 
If it is a phone and it is not smart, it is a non-smartphone